# Imposing Constraints on SVM Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, svm

I am trying to model time series data that looks similar to the made up data below

```
Sales    Store   MainSales   Distance   Temperature    Date
100      'Main'  100         0          25             20181120      
80       1       100         5          25             20181120  
65       2       100         10         25             20181120   
80       'Main'  80          0          20             20181121  
75       1       80          5          20             20181121  
70       2       80          10         20             20181121  

.....

Sales ~ f(MainSales, Distance, Temperature)
```

Relationship is non-linear and I was hoping to use something like SVM regression with RBF kernel.  My questions are

1. Are there any problems with using a subset of my dependent variable as a feature?
2. The fitted model is not very good at picking up the fact that Sales = MainSales when Distance = 0.  Is there a way to force this relationship in SVM (somewhat like rewriting the equation and forcing intercept to 0)
3. If 2 is possible can I do it using SVMLib?
4. Is there a better kind of model for this?  It looks to me somewhat like a dimension reduction but incorporating other variables

I am ultimately interesting in predicting Sales for other shops when given Sales in the main shop as well as other related data.